# Computation of integral on parametrized curve

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

if $U$ and $V$ are two open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\varphi:U\rightarrow V$ a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism, then we have the change of variable formula for the Lebesgue integral:
         $$\int_{V}f\mathsf d\lambda=\int_{U}(f\circ \phi)\times  |J_{\varphi}|\mathsf d\lambda .$$

Now, if I want to compute the Lebesgue integral on a parametrized curve $C$, with $\varphi:I\subset\mathbb R \rightarrow C\subset\mathbb R^{n}$, 
how do I obtain the following formula:
$$\int_{C}f(y)\mathsf dy=\int_{I}f(\varphi(x)) \|\triangledown \varphi(x)\|\mathsf dx$$

Comment: Where did you get this formula from? It does not look good. Since $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the LHS is the $n$-dimensional integral, but the RHS is one-dimensional. Didn't you mean a [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)?

Comment: It is the same formula as in your link.

Comment: Not quite. Integration over $V$ ($n$-dimensional) must be replaced with $C$ (one dimensional) and $dy$ (the volume element) with $ds$ (the curve length element). $\nabla\phi$ is used for a gradient (many variables, one functional value). Here it is better to write $\phi'(x)$ (the tangent vector).

Comment: There was a misprint indeed, changed V to C.